# Randomly Generate a Tree Structure Consisting of Objects with their Parents

Tags: java, random, tree

I'm trying to randomly generate a tree structure of objects that look something like the following:

```
Branch parent = new Branch("Start");
Branch branch1 = new Branch(parent, "Branch 1");
Branch branch2 = new Branch(parent, "Branch 2");
Branch branch21 = new Branch(branch2, "Branch 2.1");
Branch branch22 = new Branch(branch2, "Branch 2.2");
```

I know how to create objects manually, and how to generate random numbers, and I've seen some stuff on randomly generating nodes for creating fractals, but I'm pretty lost all the sudden, as I've never had to programmatically generate objects before.

Any ideas as to where to start, or what technique to use would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when building such items it's good to have a designed in and out. Otherwise, you will find yourself having to support many methods of application to support the intended result.

Hope this helps!

Try something along the following :)

```
Branch start = new Branch();
CreateChildren(start);

const int ChildrenLimitCheck = 0;

private void CreateChildren(Branch parent) {

    //Use a limit variable so that you can decrease, and if it's equal to a sepcific number(usually 0) exit.
    int Limit = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
     //Call the function that's recursive, inside of a function that isn't recursive. This gives you a clean way to interface with the recursive function without excessive lines of code in other areas
     generateChildren(parent,Limit);

}

private void generateChildren(Branch parent,int limit) {

    //Check to see if we've hit our minimum. If so, exit out of the logic
    if(limit == ChildrenLimitCheck)
        return;

    //Specify the random number of branches created in this instance
    int numberOfBranches = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBranches; i++) {
        Branch child = new Branch(parent);
        parent.Children.Add(child);

        //Depending on what you want to do, either pass i or pass limit. If you don't use limit, you can remove it from this function :)
        //If you pass i, try doing:
        //for (int i = numberOfBranches; i > 0; i--)
        //So that you can eventually get down to 0, to automatically stop your recursive calls with the above return statement. 
        //Seems you just want to run a loop for xxx number of times. This will still grant that, but you won't have to guess the upper limit
        //of numberOfBranches to exit on, and you'll be able to exit cleanly
       //This may be what caused your stackoverflow error. For all recursive functions, you need an exit condition or it will run indefinately
        generateChildren(child,--limit);
        //generateChildren(child,i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this quite often and I can definately help in some areas of efficiency.

Try logic similar to the following. Place a breakpoint at Console.Write to see depth. This is a C++ object oriented approach, which I personally prefer over LINQ for performance. I didn't fine tune this, so LINQ may be faster. But if you know what you're doing, you can significantly increase performance via custom methods and inheritance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    public class Branch
    {
        //Branch Name
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        //Add depth
        public List<Branch> Children = new List<Branch>();
        //Add a parent
        public Branch Parent = null;
        public Branch()
        {

        }
        public Branch(string BranchName)
        {
            this.BranchName = BranchName;
        }
        public Branch(Branch Parent, string BranchName)
        {
            this.Parent = Parent;
            this.BranchName = BranchName;
        }

        //Internal Functions
        public bool HasParent()
        {
            return this.Parent != null;
        }

        public Branch getParent()
        {
            return this.Parent;
        }
    }
    //Wrap a list inside of a class so we can have leverage over the add, and create our own functions for our need
    public class BranchList
    {
        public List<Branch> branchParentList = new List<Branch>();

        public void AddBranchToParent(Branch parent, Branch child)
        {

            foreach (Branch node in branchParentList)
            {
                if (node == parent)
                {
                    node.Children.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddBranchAsChild(string parent, Branch child)
        {

            foreach (Branch node in branchParentList)
            {
                if (node.BranchName == parent)
                {
                    node.Children.Add(child);
                    return;//Exit out, don't do the other loop. We found it
                }
                //Depth
                AddBranchAsChildInChildren(node, child,parent);
            }
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChildInChildren(Branch branch,Branch Child,string parent)
        {
            foreach(Branch child in branch.Children)
            {
                if (child.BranchName == parent)
                    child.Children.Add(Child);
            }
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChildInChildren(Branch branch, string Child, string parent)
        {
            foreach (Branch child in branch.Children)
            {
                if (child.BranchName == parent)
                    child.Children.Add(new Branch() { BranchName=Child });
            }
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChild(string parent, string child)
        {

            foreach (Branch node in branchParentList)
            {
                if (node.BranchName == parent)
                {
                    node.Children.Add(new Branch() { BranchName = child });
                    return;
                }
                //Depth
                AddBranchAsChildInChildren(node, child, parent);
            }

        }
        public void AddBranchAsParent(Branch Branch, Branch Child)
        {
            if (branchParentList.Contains(Branch) == false)
                throw new Exception("Parent exists");

            foreach (Branch b in branchParentList)
            {
                if (b == Child)
                {
                    b.Parent = Branch;
                }
            }
        }
        public void AddParent(Branch Parent)
        {
            if (branchParentList.Contains(Parent))
                throw new Exception("Parent exists");
            this.branchParentList.Add(Parent);
        }
    }
    //Wrap the list, use it as an interface
    public class BranchManager
    {
        public BranchList branchList = new BranchList();

        public BranchManager()
        {

        }
        public void AddParent(Branch Branch)
        {
            branchList.AddParent(Branch);
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChild(Branch Parent, Branch Child)
        {
            branchList.AddBranchToParent(Parent, Child);
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChild(string ParentName, Branch Child)
        {
            branchList.AddBranchAsChild(ParentName, Child);
        }
        public void AddBranchAsChild(string ParentName, string ChildName)
        {
            branchList.AddBranchAsChild(ParentName, ChildName);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             /*
                Branch parent = new Branch("Start");
                Branch branch1 = new Branch(parent, "Branch 1");
                Branch branch2 = new Branch(parent, "Branch 2");
                Branch branch21 = new Branch(branch2, "Branch 2.1");
                Branch branch22 = new Branch(branch2, "Branch 2.2");
             */
            BranchManager branchManager = new BranchManager();

            branchManager.AddParent(new Branch("Start"));

            branchManager.AddBranchAsChild("Start", "Branch 1");
            branchManager.AddBranchAsChild("Start", "Branch 2");
            branchManager.AddBranchAsChild("Branch 2", "Branch 2.1");
            branchManager.AddBranchAsChild("Branch 2", "Branch 2.2");

            Console.WriteLine(branchManager.branchList.branchParentList.Count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would this change if I wanted to set some random parameters on the size of the tree? Say for instance I wanted to have a tree that was randomly between 2-5 levels deep, and 0-5 branches per parent?

Comment: A few options, depending on your preference :). You could replace the List for an array, and specify a length in the constructor for either the parent or the children. You could use Math.Random() and carry your random integer throughout, defined in the initial scope.

Or, write a For loop with Math.Random as your second parameter (limit), and instantiate accordingly. @MattGross

Comment: Call me a super-junior dev, because you lost me there :) I get the Math.random bit, no worries there, but in the code example above, you're still specifying a list of objects to create in the Main method. I'm actually now just getting stuck on how to have a random depth and a random number of branches, without writing a loop within a loop within a loop, etc.

Comment: Yeah, it can be difficult. You have to define a way to add accessability, unless you only are going to use the logic in one aspect.

Math.Random will grant you the random number. The limit is to check against, and if it matches your condition, you exit - thus causing the recursion to exit.

When trying to write a tree structure, recursion is your best friend - however as you stated, the loops can become overwhelming. But, rest assured. The more you go through the aspects of frustration, the stronger of a developer you'll be. There's no better way to learn what not to do:) @MattGross

Answer (score 0):

Best guess so far, using a recursive function to handle the randomly generating children & parents:

```
Branch start = new Branch();
generateChildren(start);

private void generateChildren(Branch parent) {

    int numberOfBranches = (int) (Math.random() * 5);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBranches; i++) {
        Branch child = new Branch(parent);
        generateChildren(child);
    }
}
```

It properly creates a list of Branch objects with linked parents. I ran into a StackOverflow error until I wrapped it in a counter that limits the total number of branches.

The real question is: Is there a non-recursive way to handle it?